# Как посмотреть где мы поставили игнорирования в code-coverage php unit test?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, lumen

Можно ли как-то получить в coverage список мест где мы используем `@codeCoverageIgnore, @codeCoverageIgnoreStart и @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd`.
Мне нужно написать тест который будет запрещать использовать данный комментарий, в определенных случаев.  Есть ли функция для получения списка где мы используем данный комментарий?
Просто не хотелось бы писать велосипед, и проверяться во всех контролерах места где мы написали данное свойство.

Comment: Функции прям такой не знаю (хотя вы можете использовать парсер из PHPUnit, чтобы искать аннотации). Но кажется, это больше задача для какого-нибудь phpcs. Впрочем, свой велосипед может получиться проще: в хуке получите изменённые строки и поищите в них подстроку 'codeCoverageIgnore'.

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам, буду писать велосипед)